# How do I customize origdate in my bbx-file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Right now it looks like this in the PDF („Ndr.“ is the German abbreviation for „reprint“):

> Christian Kracht: Faserland. 1995, Ndr. München: Deutscher Taschenbuch Verlag 2012.

```
= author: title. origdate, address: publisher date.
```

I want to look it like this:

> Christian Kracht: Faserland. München: Deutscher Taschenbuch Verlag 2012 [1995].

```
= author: title. address: publisher date [origdate].
```

I want to change it in the same way for all kinds of entries in my .bib-file. Origdate should always be in brackets after the date.

I figured out that the code below is the section of the bbx-file (it is based on `authortitle-dw`) that defines the output. How do I have to change it to show origdate like in the above example?

```
  \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\ifbool{bbx:origfields}
    {\ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
      {\iffieldundef{origyear}
        {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
        {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
      {\iflistundef{origlocation}
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
          {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {\blxdw@warning{%
             Field 'origlocation' is set, but 'origdate' is 
             \MessageBreak%
             empty at entry '\abx@field@entrykey'.
             The 'orig' fields \MessageBreak are omitted
             for this entry}%
           \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
          {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}

\newbibmacro{loc+pub+year}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
    {}
    {\printlist{location}%
     \ifbool{bbx:nopublisher}
       {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}%
       {\iflistundef{publisher}
         {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}
         {\setunit*{\locationpublisherpunct}%
          \printlist{publisher}%
          \setunit*{\publisherdatepunct}}}}%
  \ifbool{bbx:edsuper}
    {\printfield[edition:super]{edition}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
    {}
    {\printlist{origlocation}%
     \ifbool{bbx:nopublisher}
       {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}%
       {\iflistundef{origpublisher}
         {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}
         {\setunit*{\locationpublisherpunct}%
          \printlist{origpublisher}%
          \setunit*{\publisherdatepunct}}}}%
  \ifbool{bbx:edsuper}
    {\printfield[edition:super]{edition}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{origdate}%
  \ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{punct}
    {\setunit*{\origfieldspunct}%
     \usebibmacro{origfields:loc+pub+year}}
    {\ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{parens}
      {\setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printtext[parens]{%
         \usebibmacro{origfields:loc+pub+year}}}
      {\ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{brackets}
        {\setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printtext[brackets]{%
           \usebibmacro{origfields:loc+pub+year}}}
        {\setunit*{\origfieldspunct}%
         \usebibmacro{origfields:loc+pub+year}}}}
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro{origfields:loc+pub+year}{%
  \bibstring{reprint}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
    {}
    {\printlist{location}%
     \ifbool{bbx:nopublisher}
       {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}%
       {\iflistundef{publisher}
         {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}
         {\setunit*{\locationpublisherpunct}%
          \printlist{publisher}%
          \setunit*{\publisherdatepunct}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date}}

  \newbibmacro*{origdate}{\printorigdate}
```

And here's the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{literature.bib}
    @book{kracht_faserland_2012,
        address = {München},
        title = {Faserland},
        publisher = {Deutscher Taschenbuch Verlag},
        author = {Kracht, Christian},
        date = {2012},
        origdate = {1995}
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twoside=false,fontsize=12pt,toc=bibliography,toc=listof]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-dw,series=afteryear,firstfull,nopublisher=false,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
              \addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

Dies ist ein Beispielsatz.\footnote{Vgl. \cite[76]{kracht_faserland_2012}.}

\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where does `vauthorstyle-dw` come from? I can't find it on CTAN. And it will make your question easier to answer if you provide a full [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: My fault, mispelled it for some reason. Now there is the correct name: It's authortitle-dw. You should find it at CTAN. Also added a MWEB.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the most elegant of solutions but it works for me. You have to change some punctuaction commands and change the order of the elements:

```
    \newbibmacro*{origdate}{\printorigdate}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:origfields}
    {\ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
      {\iffieldundef{origyear}
        {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
        {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
      {\iflistundef{origlocation}
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
          {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}
        {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {\blxdw@warning{%
             Field 'origlocation' is set, but 'origdate' is 
             \MessageBreak%
             empty at entry '\abx@field@entrykey'.
             The 'orig' fields \MessageBreak are omitted
             for this entry}%
           \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
          {\usebibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}

\newbibmacro{loc+pub+year}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
    {}
    {\printlist{location}%
   \ifbool{bbx:nopublisher}
       {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}%
       {\iflistundef{publisher}
         {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}
         {\setunit*{\locationpublisherpunct}%
          \printlist{publisher}%
           \setunit*{\addspace}}}}%
  \ifbool{bbx:edsuper}
    {\printfield[edition:super]{edition}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  }

\newbibmacro{origloc+origpub+origyear}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:nolocation}
    {}
    {\printlist{origlocation}%
  \ifbool{bbx:nopublisher}
       {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}%
       {\iflistundef{origpublisher}
         {\setunit*{\locationdatepunct}}
         {\setunit*{\locationpublisherpunct}%
          \printlist{origpublisher}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}}}}%
  \ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{punct}
    {\setunit*{\origfieldspunct}%
     \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}
    {\ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{parens}
      {\setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printtext[parens]{%
         \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}
      {\ifdefstring{\bbx@origfieldsformat}{brackets}
        {\setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printtext[brackets]{%
           \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}
        {\setunit*{\origfieldspunct}%
         \usebibmacro{loc+pub+year}}}}
         \usebibmacro{origdate}%
  \newunit}
```